# Using ICP inspectors in ethzasl_icp_mapper package

Tags: ros, icp, ethzasl-icp-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been using the package [ethzasl_icp_mapper](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapper) to build 3D maps.
Now I would like to use the inspector provided in the package.  But when I enable the PerformanceInspector in the icp.yaml file like this:

```
readingDataPointsFilters:
  - RandomSamplingDataPointsFilter:
      prob: 0.2

matcher:
  KDTreeMatcher:
    maxDist: 0.3
    epsilon: 3.16

outlierFilters:
  - TrimmedDistOutlierFilter:
      ratio: 0.75

errorMinimizer:
  PointToPlaneErrorMinimizer

transformationCheckers:
  - DifferentialTransformationChecker:
      minDiffRotErr: 0.001
      minDiffTransErr: 0.01
      smoothLength: 4
  - CounterTransformationChecker:
      maxIterationCount: 40
  - BoundTransformationChecker:
      maxRotationNorm: 0.8
      maxTranslationNorm: 0.4

inspector:
#  VTKFileInspector
#  NullInspector
   PerformanceInspector:
      baseFileName: matcher-output
#      dumpPerfOnExit: 1
```

I get the error saying:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PointMatcherSupport::Parametrizable::InvalidParameter'
 what(): Parameter baseFileName for module PerformanceInspector was set but is not used
```

Then the roslaunch exits.

When I enable the VTKInspector it works and the terminal shows the message that it is writing the data to some files which begin with baseFileName: *point-matcher-output*
but I am not able to find out the location of these file written.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71659/using-icp-inspectors-in-ethzasl_icp_mapper-package./) by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The full answer was posted on GitHub:
https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping/issues/12

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [Francois](https://answers.ros.org/users/4341/francois/) with karma: 101 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1